# Does two columns have any equal value? SQLite

Tags: sqlite

In two columns within the same table (idParent1 and idParent2), I want to know if there are any two equal ids in any row (not just in the same row). If there are equal values (in any row) I want to obtain these ids.

I try this without success.

```
SELECT idParent1
FROM
Person
WHERE
Person.idParent1 IN Person.idParent2;
```

I'm getting the error: no such table: Person.idParent2

Example:

```
sqlite> CREATE TABLE Person(
ID INT PRIMARY KEY     NOT NULL,
Parent1           INT    NOT NULL,
Parent2            INT     NOT NULL,
);

INSERT INTO Person (ID,Parent1,Parent2)
VALUES (1, 2,3);
INSERT INTO Person (ID,Parent1,Parent2)
VALUES (2, 5,6);
INSERT INTO Person (ID,Parent1,Parent2)
VALUES (3, 7,5);
INSERT INTO Person (ID,Parent1,Parent2)
VALUES (9, 10,12);
INSERT INTO Person (ID,Parent1,Parent2)
VALUES (45, 2,3);
```

In this example 5 is common in Parent1 and Parent2. I want to identify all the values like 5 are present in both columns

Comment: please provide ddl and sample data

Comment: SQLite... I will provide a Sample data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check only for `idParent1`:

```
SELECT idParent1
FROM
Person
WHERE
  Person.idParent1 IN (
    SELECT 
      idParent2 
    FROM
      Person
  );
```

or

```
SELECT idParent1
FROM
Person AS p
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Person WHERE Person.idParent2 = p.idParent1);
```

A similar solution can apply to `idParent2`.

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is not correct.  The correct syntax is:

```
SELECT idParent1 FROM Person WHERE idParent1 IN (SELECT idParent2 FROM Person)
```